# How to add php within jquery

Tags: functions, jquery

I want to add php code within jquery. I know that the file then cannot be saved as a js file but must be saved as a php file to execute the php code. If we save it as a php file then it can also not be enqueued within function.php.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#a, #b').change(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this), // Get a handle on the checkbox we just clicked.
        $a = jQuery('#a'),
        $b = jQuery('#b'),
        $c = jQuery('#c'),    // Get a handle on the textbox.
        $d = jQuery('#d'),    // Get a handle on the textbox.
        $e = jQuery('#e'),    // Get a handle on the textbox.
        $f = jQuery('#f'),    // Get a handle on one of our default values.
        $g = jQuery('#g');    // Get a handle on one of our default values.

if ($this.attr('id') == 'a' && $this.is(':checked')) {
   // Clicking checkbox a will add the content of c and f and place it in e
   // It will also uncheck checkbox b.

   $e.val( <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('m')); ?> );
   $b.removeAttr('checked');
} else if ($this.attr('id') == 'b' && $this.is(':checked')) {
   // Clicking checkbox b will add the content of d and g and place it in e
   // It will also uncheck checkbox a.

   $e.val( <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('m')); ?> );
   $a.removeAttr('checked');
} else {
   $e.val('');
}
});
});
```

So how can I add php within my jquery and integrate it within my function.php theme file. Also please be noted that the php echo will return a javascript code so will it be possible that this code will be just added as a text and not echo as an executed code. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for you to use PHP in your JavaScript file. Enqueue your script properly using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook and then use the [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)function to pass your data to your JavaScript code.

```
<?php
function wpa67325_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle', 'filename.js', false );
    $translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa67325_enqueue_scripts', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your help. Actually I have recently read an article about wp_localize_script() function and I didn't know anything about it before that. So I am completely novice to it. My actual requirement is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751766/how-can-i-dynamically-edit-jw-player-javascript . Please read my comment below that question for clarification. That's what I really want to accomplish. Please if you can answer it, I'll be very thankful to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily save your file as PHP file and enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script` function without any problem.
There is nothing wrong in serving JS in a PHP file.

Comment: Thanks Hamed for your quick response. The point I am worry about is that the php code that is., <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('m')); ?> is going to give javascript code like that                                                <div>My code</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> ... some jquery code....</script> so will it be possible that it'll be just returned as a text and not an executed code when put into the textbox with the id e.

Comment: Ahhhh... I'm not sure I understand what you said. The whole point is that using php in javascript is a common practice. When you include javascript file using `<script src=...` the content is considered javascript code and therefor treated as such.

Comment: So do you have any idea how I can accomplish this. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: **More explanation**: What you need to do is just save your code as a php file and then use it as you would use a simple js file. I don't know how to say it more clearly.